# Using `setxkbmap` to swap esc, but not working consistently

Tags: bash, keyboard-layout

I currently have the following line in my `~/.bashrc` to swap <kbd>caps lock</kbd> and <kbd>esc</kbd>: `/usr/bin/setkbmap -option "caps:swapescape"`. Sometimes, when I boot up my computer, it works flawlessly. Other times <kbd>caps lock</kbd> still works as <kbd>caps lock</kbd> and <kbd>esc</kbd> still works as <kbd>esc</kbd>.

What might be going on here? Is this line reverting the mapping every time I boot up, so it will alternate working and not working?

Thank you! Please let me know if you have a better alternative. I'm running Debian (Pop!_os).

Answer (score 2):

`~/.bashrc` will only be run when you open a terminal emulator.  To have it run automatically at login you will want to have it elsewhere (depending on how you login).  For me, this would be in `~/.xinitrc`.

Per the [debian wiki](https://wiki.debian.org/EnvironmentVariables): `Graphical logins do not read a shell's startup files (/etc/profile and ~/.profile and so on) by default, but you as a user may choose to create a ~/.xsessionrc file which does this.`

Comment: This is probably the right answer. If you run a GUI desktop environment, you can also add a script with your command to its autostart script directory. For KDE, it's in `$HOME/.config/autostart-scripts`. For Gnome, Preferences->Sessions->Startup Programs->Add should work.

Answer (score 1):

There could be another problem. If you are using `setxkbmap` and you previously set the *capslock* behaviour it will stack the options if you do not reset them (using `-option ''`, see [`man setxkbmap`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/setxkbmap*)).
Hint: Use the *verbose* option `-v` to display the options, aka *symbols* settings

### Example

Activate mapping capslock to escape:

```
$ setxkbmap -option caps:escape -v
...
symbols:    ...+capslock(escape)+...
...
```

No let's undo the mapping (wrong way)

```
$ setxkbmap -option caps:capslock -v
...
symbols:    ...+capslock(capslock)+capslock(escape)+...
...
```

As you can see the old option is still present. To clear *all* options it use following command:

```
$ setxkbmap -option '' -v
...
symbols:    ...
...
```